# Typescript does not infer parsed attributes from a flat attributes function

Tags: typescript

I have a function where is responsible to flat the object attributes.

```
async function query<T = {}>(query: string): Promise<T> {
  return Promise.resolve({
    value: 'random value here',
    randomAttribute: 'randomValue'
  }) as any
}

type QueryResult<T> = {
  id: string
  data: T
}

async function runSomeQuery() {
  const result = await query<QueryResult<{ name: string, age: string }>>('SELECT SOMETHING FROM ANOTHER THING')
  const parsedResult = flatResult(result)
  return parsedResult.name
}

function flatResult<T extends QueryResult<{}>>(queryResult: T) {
  return {
    id: queryResult.id,
    ...queryResult.data
  }
}
```

But the `flatResult()` inferred return type is missing the name and age attributes so when I try to do `parsedResult.name` I get an error.

Link for playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwI4IKYBOYAPACowC8MA3gL4B8AFLoWAFwwjIGoQDmASg4AFAugC2qEHjL0aAKBgwCeZAgJZREqXgB0KkOgA2ANzyNqipTBPAj+DgHICwCABMJNu-hgALQniOADRWSi7uEgCCyNyoAEYIyHhO4R7iAGregVa0AjCg+RBg8rTy8shgAA54MACK+EQASnggCEbIspQKSqhuHFw8-FZuwMjAHKQlZaCQsIgoGFgESADKEnj1rIx5lkpQmFzKLW3IXcAA7sCopyxExJtNx+3E1DAQwOLJnLH8Qfl8XwGvD4MAYTEcKwAogAZSEAYXIKwA8gBZSGkAASAEkAHIAcRgADFGqiYJEcUjMZDGjBMbi8Y4BFZ9hBDpVgARpG5mq12l04EZRjyTowDCcmWFVOosOzOXhuU9kLp3p8pvJ5lA0Jh4ILkMLnuQ8AAPJLuEB1BpgfUdOj0Ji3K2KiY7KwqNQabrWXocB3W3S9ELWGC6EO+xW6EZjHIlIA

So, what should I do to have this inferred right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rely on type argument interference in TypeScript Generics: i.e. let the argument passed into `flatResult()` determine the return type:

```
function flatResult<T>(queryResult: QueryResult<T>) {
  return {
    id: queryResult.id,
    ...queryResult.data
  }
}
```

The reason why this works is because the compiler will look at the type of the arugment `queryResult`. When you call/invoke `flatResult` in this line:

```
// In the line below, `result` has the correct inferred type
const result = await query<QueryResult<{ name: string, age: string }>>('SELECT SOMETHING FROM ANOTHER THING')

// And this type will be passed into `flatResult()` and available to the generic type
const parsedResult = flatResult(result)
```

You actually are alreayd informing `flatResult` that `result`'s type should be whatever it is, which is typed as `QueryResult<{ name: string, age: string }>`.

[See proof-of-concept example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwI4IKYBOYAPACowC8MA3gL4B8AFLoWAFwwjIGoQDmASg4AFAugC2qEHjL0aAKBgwCeZAgJZREqXgB0KkOgA2ANzyNqipTBPAj+DgHICwCABMJNu-hgALQniOADRWSi7uEgCCyNyoAEYIyHhO4R7iAGregVa0AjCg+RBg8rTy8shgAA54MACK+EQASnggCEbIspQKSqhuHFw8-FZuwMjAHKQlZaCQsIgoGFgESADKEnj1rIx5lkpQmFzKLW3IXcAA7sCopyxExJtNx+3E1DAQwOLJnLH8Qfl8XwGvD4MAYTEcKwAogAZSEAYXIKwA8gBZSGkAASAEkAHIAcRgADFGqiYJEcUjMZDGjBMbi8Y4BFZ9hBDpVgARpG5mq12l04EZRjyTowDCcmWFVOosOzOXhuU9kLp3p8pvJ5lA0Jh4ILkMLnqQmLcwPrkBwHibFbIdlYVGoNN1rL0OMbTbpeiFrDBdD7XYrdCMxjkpkA).

Comment: Thank you soo much for this. I thought when you define a generic type you have to explicitly define it on the function call like flatResult<MyType>.

Comment: @BrunoQuaresma No problem at all! More than happy to help. It's actually something new I learned a few days ago too, when struggling with inferred types.